# How can I set up a mean stack app with mean.io which uses angular 1.4 and bower?

Tags: mean-stack, mean.io

I want to code an app in angular 1.4 and for that I came across mean.io the best scaffolding tool presently.But when i downloaded it,i got webpack and tons of various unfamiliar stuff.Please tell me how i can download a mean.io app which uses angular 1.4 or if not then a nice scaffolding tool for angular 1.4 and steps to install it.That would be a great help !
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is head over to the Github page for the mean.io framekwork at this link [Mean.io Github version 0.7.0](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/tree/0.7.0).  From there take a look at the read me and scroll follow the instructions.

You'll need to install mongo database on your machine and make sure its running each time you want to run your application.  Here is a good link, follow it step by step. [MongoDB install - windows](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi3pO2s3e3UAhWGGz4KHVeyA7YQtwIIJjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D1uFY60CESlM&usg=AFQjCNGQbNs857_vuMbH6tM76Lfdj1qunw)

Then you will have to have the latest version of node.js installed. It can be installed here. [node js download](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

You will also need to install the latest version of Git to your machine. It can be installed here [Git download](https://git-scm.com/downloads)

Once the above are done, you will need to navigate to a directory on your computer using the command prompt/terminal and type the following commands. I suggest you go to C:\Users\YourName

```
npm install -g npm
npm update -g
npm install -g mean-cli
npm install -g bower
```

They will take some time so be patient.

Then type this command to clone the boilerplate code to your machine

```
mean init <yourAppTitle>
```

When that is done change directories into the project folder you just made like this

```
cd yourAppTitle
```

Then inside this folder type the following commands to install to your project

```
npm install
bower install
```

You may see some warning signs/errors and you can ignore them for now and proceed.

Finally, type this command inside your project folder - this will start your app. Remember to have mongodb running simultaneously or this will not work

```
gulp
```

Head over to your browser and type in localhost:3000

You should see the boilerplate code.

If you cannot get Mean.io working you can try installing a different angular scaffold here - [angular scaffold](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#angular-docs). Read through the readme file and you will see steps to install the angular scaffold

Comment: I did these steps and it is still scaffolding my app with webpack instead of bower.json.

Comment: what do you mean it is still scaffolding with webpack instead of bower.json

Comment: you have provided no error messages or details, I cannot help you without that information

Comment: There is no error !! All I wanted was to have a bower.json file and after following your steps it is giving me a webpack file.I NEED A BOWER.JSON FILE !

Comment: this is the error when i did bower install:{bower ENOENT        No bower.json present}

Comment: why dont you try being resourceful and do a google search